# Get row id in sqlite when iterating over a fetchall?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to get the id of the row as I iterate over it, but can't seem to figure out how. Here's what I have.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Logs {} ORDER BY created {} LIMIT 0, {}".format(created_filter, settings.order, settings.limit))

logs = list()
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # I want to get the row id in here.
```

Here's where I create and write to the DB. Everything is working except apparently my row ids.

```
file = settings.logs_path
log_table_name = 'Logs'
pin_table_name = 'Pins'


conn = sqlite3.connect(file, check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

log_schema = dict(rowid = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT',
            asctime = 'TEXT',
            created = 'REAL',
            exc_info = 'TEXT',
            exc_text = 'TEXT',
            filename = 'TEXT',
            funcName = 'TEXT',
            levelname = 'TEXT',
            levelno = 'INTEGER',
            lineno = 'INTEGER',
            module = 'TEXT',
            msecs = 'REAL',
            message = 'TEXT',
            msg = 'TEXT',
            name = 'TEXT',
            pathname = 'TEXT',
            process = 'INTEGER',
            processName = 'TEXT',
            relativeCreated = 'REAL',
            thread = 'INTEGER',
            threadName = 'TEXT')

pin_schema = dict(rowid = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT',
                pinnedId = 'INTEGER')

sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + log_table_name + ' ({})'.format(','.join(log_schema))
c.execute(sql)
sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + pin_table_name + ' ({})'.format(','.join(pin_schema))
c.execute(sql)
conn.commit()

def write_log(log):
    keys = [key for key in log_schema.keys() if key != 'rowid']
    values = []
    for key in keys:
        try:
            values.append(str(getattr(log, key)))
        except Exception:
            values.append('')
    parameters = ['?' for key in keys]
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Logs ({}) VALUES ({})".format(','.join(keys),','.join(parameters)), values)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: If the ID is, for example, the first column in your table you can access it this way: `row[0]`

Comment: Perhaps my problem is not what I think it is. My rowid field is always None.

Comment: Ah, are you even getting results back?

Comment: Yeah. Everything is working. I'm writing to my database and reading from it successfully, I just can't seem to get the ids of the rows I'm getting back. I'm adding my schema/table creating code, as maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: Yes, that could very well be the problem. SQLite has a special way of creating the autoincrementing rowid. I will refresh my memory on that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CREATE TABLE` commands are lacking field types. Notice what happens here:

```
In [27]: pin_schema = dict(rowid = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT',
                pinnedId = 'INTEGER')

In [30]: pin_table_name = 'Pins'

In [31]: sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + pin_table_name + ' ({})'.format(','.join(pin_schema))

In [32]: sql
Out[32]: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pins (pinnedId,rowid)'
```

All you get are the field names with no field types. Instead, either define `pin_schema` and `log_schema` as lists of strings which include both the field and the field type, or iterate through `pin_schema.items()`:

```
sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + pin_table_name + ' ({})'.format(
    ', '.join('{f} {t}'.format(f=field, t=field_type)
             for field, field_type in pin_schema.items()))

In [35]: sql
Out[35]: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pins (pinnedId INTEGER, rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)'
```

The lack of field types explains why the `rowid` was not autoincrementing.